# ffmpeg command on windows wamp server

Tags: php, ffmpeg

this is linux server command

/usr/bind/ffmpeg -i and so on.....

i have installed ffmpeg in wamp server on localhost it is showing its extension in phpinfo()

than what should be the command

either just

ffmpeg -i

or anypath/ffmpeg -i

Comment: Why not try it out? Usually, it would be some path starting with C:\Program Files\......

Comment: could you please explain it in detail

Comment: If you don't find the ffmpeg.exe, download it from here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ (recommended by http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html). After that, just copy ffmeg.exe to c:\ and start using it.

Comment: The DDL files I mentioned need to be registered or placed in `windows\system32`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the ffmpeg_php.dll file that is installed as a PHP extension there should also be a ffmpeg.exe file.

I do not know exactly where as I do not use wamp but there should be one. Including some aditional DLL files for the codes it will support.

```
avcodec-51.dll
avformat-51.dll
avutil-49.dll
pthreadGC2.dll
```

Then you can call it like this: `C:\path\to\ffmpeg.exe-i and so on....`